# Apache Knox config

Tags: hadoop

The following URL works
curl -X GET 'http://10.1.1.1:50070/webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS'

and returns
Expires: Thu, 07 May 2015 04:19:20 GMT
Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 04:19:20 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.hwx)

{"FileStatuses":{"FileStatus":[
{"accessTime":0,"blockSize":0,"
....

The documentation on 
http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/securing-hadoop-infrastructure-apache-knox/

says to use Knox, you enter:
curl -iku guest:guest-password -X GET 'https://localhost:8443/gateway/sandbox/webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS'

I've tried this and I just get "Page Not Found" error returned in a HTML page.  I'm guessing the issue is "/sandbox/".  Entering /10.1.1.1:50070/ doesn't work so I need to define this somewhere.  I have

/conf/topologies/admin.xml
/conf/topologies/default.xml

Within default.xml, I have a service with WEBHDFS defined.  I'm guessing I just need a way to reference this default.xml for it to work.  So, I tried:
'https://localhost:8443/gateway/default/WEBHDFS/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS'

and it still didn't work.  The format for the URL is: 
Gateway https://{gateway-host}:{gateway-port}/{gateway-path}/{cluster-name}/oozie

So, where is {cluster-name} defined?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use lower case webhdfs in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Clustername and configure were defined in xml files which stored at directory conf/topologies/{clustername}.xml